# NestJS gRPC request parameters validation

Tags: validation, parameters, request, nestjs, grpc

I am trying to achieve a parameters validation on request sent to my **gRPC** service built with *NestJS*, that's how my example method looks like:

```
@GrpcMethod('Service', 'Method')
methodName(request: Request, _metadata: Metadata, call: ServerWritableStreamImpl<Request, Observable<Response>>) {
    ...
}
```

We use *proto* files to define request and response interfaces.

How to validate request parameters and return/throw an exception with e.g. **BAD_REQUEST** code?

So far I've tried:

- use @Body / @Payload decorators on request and class-validator package to add decorators like @IsNotEmpty() or @IsEnum() - does not work and we lose a control over call object (it's undefined), since, i suppose, now this request is treated as a normal HTTP request and not like gRPC call
- use ValidationSchema from class-validator package (https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#defining-validation-schema-without-decorators) but it's broken for some time (https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/595)

Comment: Difficult to tell without a proto file but GRPC is actually validating against the object defined in the Proto file. So it should not be possible to send objects that are different than expected.

Comment: Yeah, it does appear to empty out fields that are invalid before sending the request. For instance though, you cannot strongly type a UUID, or email, or anything like that in protos, so need to handle them in your controller. I'm having a similar issue, not sure what to do without duplicating the contract and adding class validator decorators :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom decorator to validate input parameters with `class-validator` and DTOs. Try it out:

```js
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';

export function ValidateGrpcInput(dtoClass: any) {
  return function (
    target: any,
    methodName: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
  ) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
      const [data] = args;
      const object = plainToInstance(dtoClass, data);
      const errors = await validate(object);

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        throw new RpcException({
          code: grpc.status.INVALID_ARGUMENT,
          message: 'Input data validation failed',
        });
      }

      return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    };
  };
}
```

Then use this decorator in your grpc controller like that:

```js
@GrpcMethod('UserService', 'getUser')
@ValidateGrpcInput(GetUserRequestDto)
async getUser(data: GetUserRequestDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
  /* Your controller logic here */
}
```